# how to create a joint list of files in a 2 folders

Tags: batch-file

**BACKGROUND**

I'm trying to create a [joint] list of (just) the file names from two different folders, namely `FULL_REMOTE_DIR` and `FULL_LOCAL_DIR`

**CODE**

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
TITLE Demo Mode
ECHO small script to showcase
ECHO how to iterate folders
SET mypath=%cd%
SET "remote_dir=\remote\*"
SET "local_dir=\local\*"
SET "other_dir=\other\*"

SET "FULL_REMOTE_DIR=%mypath%%remote_dir%"
SET "FULL_LOCAL_DIR=%mypath%%local_dir%"
SET "FULL_OTHER_DIR=%mypath%%other_dir%"

ECHO REMOTE DIR:
FOR %%a IN ("%FULL_REMOTE_DIR%") DO (
   SET REMOTE_DIR_LIST=%%a
   ECHO %%a)

ECHO LOCAL DIR: 
FOR %%a IN ("%FULL_LOCAL_DIR%") DO ECHO %%a

ECHO OTHER DIR: 
FOR %%a IN ("%FULL_OTHER_DIR%") DO ECHO %%a
```

**QUESTION**

How can I create a list of files that are in `FULL_REMOTE_DIR` and `FULL_LOCAL_DIR`

Comment: You're asking two separate questions. First, you're asking how to create the list of files. Second, you're asking how to compare two lists of files, which is a totally different topic. You need to break this into two separate questions, each in its own post.

Comment: @KenWhite is this to your liking?

Comment: Much better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
cd /D %~dp0
set _filelist=,
for /f "delims=|" %%f in ('dir FULL_REMOTE_DIR_PATH  /b %CD%') do (
set "_filelist=!_filelist!,%%f"
)
set _filelist=%_filelist:,,=%
echo %_filelist%
```

You need to run it from the FULL_LOCAL_DIR, it should create a list of FULL_LOCAL_DIR + FULL_REMOTE_DIR.